# How to add foreach to Request $request in Controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have a post route and I wanted to add foreach loop to the requests like this:

```
public function updateProductAttrsInfo(Request $request, $id)
    {
        foreach($request as $req){
            dd($req);
        }
    }
```

But this is wrong because $request is an object and not an array so when can not apply foreach to that.

So I wonder how can I properly apply foreach to this `$request` ?

Comment: Why do you want to loop over the request? Do you pass an array?

Comment: I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but you can actually iterate through object properties: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
foreach($request->all() as $k => $v){}
```